# Query to join two tables and update one based on the counts from the other

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, aggregate-functions

Let us say I have 2 tables `Queues` and `QueuesMeta` with the following sample data:

`Queues`:

| QueueId | ItemName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pencil |
| 1 | Eraser |
| 2 | Pencil |
| 2 | Eraser |
| 2 | Ruler |

`QueuesMeta`:

| QueuesMetaId | QueueId | Capacity | IsCountMatch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | No |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | No |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | No |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | No |

I need an update query that I plan to use in a stored procedure that would update the `IsCountMatch` column (pre-filled with "No") in the `QueuesMeta` table to either "Yes" or "No" based on whether the record count for the `QueueId` in the `Queues` table matches the stated capacity in the `QueuesMeta` table.

So, after the query is run, the `QueuesMeta` table should look like this:

`QueuesMeta` (updated):

| QueuesMetaId | QueueId | Capacity | IsCountMatch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | Yes |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | Yes |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | No |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | No |

The `QueueId` in `QueuesMeta` table is not a unique column.

I have come up with a query that looks like this:

```
UPDATE QueuesMeta 
SET IsCountMatch = 'Yes'
WHERE QueueId IN (SELECT Q.QueueId
                  FROM QueuesMeta QM
                  INNER JOIN Queues Q ON QM.QueueId = Q.QueueId
                  WHERE QM.IsCountMatch = 'No'
                  GROUP BY QM.QueueId, QM.Capacity
                  HAVING QM.Capacity = COUNT(Q.QueueId))
```

But this does not seem to be working. A quick check reveals that because the `QueueId` is not unique in the `QueuesMeta` table, the `COUNT(Q.QueueId)` portion is returning a count of 6 (3 entries in `QueuesMeta` and 2 in `Queues`) instead of just 2.

Appreciate any help with the query.

Comment: There seems to be a data modelling issue here. What if you have two records in `QueuesMeta` with Queueid=1 and capacity=2, and the queue count matches, do you update both records?

Comment: Yes, that would be what I am looking for. But this is anyway a made-up scenario with made up table structures, column names and data. Because of security concerns, I had to come up with something that mimicked my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have an extra join on `QueuesMeta`.

This type of thing is much easier to do with a correlated `EXISTS`. You simply want to know if the number of `Queues` rows that match by `QueueId` is the same as `Capacity`.

```sql
UPDATE QM
SET IsCountMatch = 'Yes'
FROM QueuesMeta QM
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM Queues Q
    WHERE QM.QueueId = Q.QueueId
    -- implicitly group by empty set
    HAVING QM.Capacity = COUNT(*)
)
  AND QM.IsCountMatch = 'No';
```

You can also use a correlated comparison

```sql
UPDATE QM
SET IsCountMatch = 'Yes'
FROM QueuesMeta QM
WHERE QM.Capacity = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Queues Q
    WHERE QM.QueueId = Q.QueueId
    -- implicitly group by empty set
)
  AND QM.IsCountMatch = 'No';
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q0vcjLda)

Answer (score 1):

it can be done using an `inner join` with the set of queues and their counts :

```
update q
set IsCountMatch = 'Yes'
from QueuesMeta q
inner join (
  select QueueId, count(1) as count
  from Queues
  group by QueueId
) as s on s.QueueId = q.QueueId and s.count = q.Capacity
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/UDQVYrl9)

Answer (score 0):

Incase you need to update Yes and No according to the record change

```
;with Counts as (SELECT COUNT(q.QueueId) cnt, Q.QueueId FROM Queues Q GROUP BY Q.QueueId)
UPDATE QM SET QM.IsCountMatch = (CASE C.cnt WHEN QM.Capacity THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END)
FROM QueuesMeta QM INNER JOIN Counts C ON QM.QueueId = C.QueueId
```

If you just want to update to Yes

```
;with Counts as (SELECT COUNT(q.QueueId) cnt, Q.QueueId FROM Queues Q GROUP BY Q.QueueId)
UPDATE QM SET QM.IsCountMatch = 'Yes'
FROM QueuesMeta QM INNER JOIN Counts C ON 
QM.QueueId = C.QueueId AND C.Cnt =  QM.Capacity AND QM.IsCountMatch ='No'
```